# How can I remap mousebuttons in macos mojave

Tags: macos, mojave, mouse, input-source, keybindings

I use a wireless mouse (Anker vertical wireless) and the buttons which are supposed to go back or forward in a browser just turn on scrolling by mouse-movement. I'd like to remap these two buttons to their original purpose but have failed to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works like a charm and is free software: https://sensible-side-buttons.archagon.net/